# How to properly managing large StateObjects and Intercommunication Among ViewModels in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to seek help with a way to either better manage large `@StateObject`s or referencing other `@StateObject`s in another `@StateObject`.

I am targeting mainly iPadOS, version 15.6 and above. I am using purely SwiftUI and an MVVM architecture.

### Example

I have a simple view structure below, with a `MainView`, `SettingsView`, `UserView`, and `ExportView`. I've replaced a lot of the unnecessary code, but for this context the `SettingViewModel` holds a lot of the methods for the `SettingView`, `UserView`, `ExportView` and any of the other sub views too.

It essentially has become so overgrown with all the methods, variables, and functionality.

```swift
struct MainView: View {
  @State private var isSettingsOpen: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
      Button("Open settings") {
        isSettingsOpen = true
      }
      .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isSettingsOpen) {
        SettingView(isSettingsOpen: $isSettingsOpen)
      }
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {
  @Binding var isSettingsOpen: Bool
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      Form {
        NavigationLink("View users") {
          UserView()
        }
        NavigationLink("Export settings") {
          ExportView()
        }
      }
      .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
          Button("Close") {
            isSettingsOpen = false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct UserView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Users")
  }
}

struct ExportView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Export")
  }
}

final class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var users: [User] = []
  func getUsers() {
    // .. fetch users
  }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

Because of this structure, I *have* been able to reuse a lot of code for `getUsers()` and other CRUD actions for example.

However, managing the whole VM has been very difficult and sometimes I end up overloading it with duplicate data or performing things wrong to other methods.

### What I tried

I tried extracting the portions of the ViewModel into smaller view models for each View. So I ended up with:

- SettingsView
- SettingsViewModel
- UserView
- UserViewModel
- ExportView
- ExportViewModel

This worked until there were shared `@Published` properties from the `SettingsView` needed in the `UserView` or `UserViewModel`.

It meant I tried then initialising the other relevant view models in other view models:

```swift
final class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject {
  let userVM: UserViewModel = UserViewModel()
  let exportVM: ExportViewModel = ExportViewModel()
  @Published var users: [User] = []
  func getUsers() {
    // .. fetch users
  }
}
```

And vice-versa for the other view models.

It started to become even more complex because I felt I was looping so much and sometimes referencing one view model for one method alone, when previously in the large `SettingsViewModel` it was all accessible.

#### Things I ran into

I also then had other issues because if I initialised `UserViewModel` inside `ExportViewModel` the compiler would throw some errors (I don't have a reference because of debugging and didn't save a checkpoint).

What I do remember is I ended up with some really ridiculous code where it was along the lines of:

```swift
final class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
  var settingsVM: SettingsViewModel
  var exportVM: ExportViewModel
  init(settingsVM: SettingsViewModel, exportVM: ExportViewModel) {
    self.settingsVM = settingsVM
    self.exportVM = exportVM
  }
}
```

At this point I was so far over my head I've reverted back to the original single SettingsViewModel.

### My question / help needed

Is there an appropriate way that I can link or manage large view models in SwiftUI?

For example, another issue I had was in my `SettingsViewModel` there was a `@Published` property `isEditModeActive`.

This is used in more than the `NavigationStack` but inside other sub-views. Or referencing CRUD operations which were displaying `ErrorAlert` model which was re-used throughout all the other sub-views.

In this example, `ErrorAlert` would accept the message and action types (one button or two). But splitting the view models meant I couldn't access that property correctly, or where I could the alert wouldn't end up firing or displaying.

Other parts where I wanted to extract out were `@Published` properties for Toggles, or user options. Having them in the `SettingsViewModel` meant that they were cluttering up the first 1/4 of the document.

If I could extract them into individual view models, then it would compartmentalise the variables too, and make it more manageable.

### Intended solution

I am hoping if there is a good way to be able to access multiple VMs from other VMs - almost like an `.environmentObject()` but to apply to other view models.

```swift
// .. invalid code
@StateObject private var settingsVM = SettingsViewModel()
 .environmentObject(userVM)
 .environmentObject(exportVM)

@StateObject private var userVM = UserViewModel()
 .environmentObject(settingVM)
 .environmentObject(exportVM)

@StateObject private var exportVM = ExportViewModel()
 .environmentObject(settingVM)
 .environmentObject(userVM)
```

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to better structure and manage large `@StateObject`s in SwiftUI. How can I refactor my code to ensure efficient ViewModel interaction, maintainability, and improved code reuse?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: ViewModels should never talk to each other or even know about each other. Move any common data down to a Manager. Also don’t overdue the ObservableObjects they are inefficient and when iOS 17 goes public they will be essentially phased out. Apple has created a better version

Comment: yeah i understand that, but how would i go about it in an app targeting v15.6+

Comment: Add a Manager layer that contains any common code.

Comment: @loremipsum sorry if this is a dumb question, but what is a Manager layer, and in this scenario? Like a singleton?

Comment: Maybe, or something setup with dependency injection  or create your own property wrappers, etc. you can use Combine or work directly with SwiftUI’s environment.